# Calculating 2D parabolic trajectory for a projectile to hit a position

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unity3d-2dtools, projectile

I'm developing a Tower defense in 2D in Unity.

I'm trying to calculate a parabola to draw the trajectory of the projectiles fired from a tower in the game. I've got the position of the tower and the position of the enemy - now I need an algorithm that calculates a parabola that will hit the enemy.

Is there a universal algorithm or something like that for this kind of calculation?

Comment: After 1min googling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29

Comment: This [Link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55419/aim-prediction-along-a-parabola-how-to-make-a-tower-defence-mortar-aim-accurat) might solve your question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming gravity but no drag we have:

- [image]
- [image]

where

- x, y is displacement
- x_0, y_0 is initial location
- u_x, u_y is initial velocity
- g is acceleration due to gravity
- t is time elapsed